# Make a div not scroll in ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework

In my code iam having 2 portions. In the first portion iam using a list card div. Then in the second portion iam displaying some images. Now i need these images div to be scrollable since there will  be more images. But the 1st div not to scroll. Here is my code:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list >
        <ion-item nav-clear class="item item-primary"  >
            <div class="list card">    //This is the first div that does not need scrolling
                <h2>{{customerDetail.name}}</h2>   
                <p>{{customerDetail.place}}</p>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
        <div class="card"> //This is the second div
            <i class="ion-ios-pricetags button-top-right" style="z-index:10"> </i>
            <i class="icon ion-clock button-top-left" style="z-index:10"> {{order.time}}</i>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <img ng-src="photos/{{order.url}}.jpg" style="height:100px;width:100px;"> 
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
</ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

I tried using position:fixed for the first div but it makes the div arrangment irregular. Is there any way possible????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should share some css as well, maybe a jsfiddle. You might want to set the card class after the ion list element. You can also try set specific heights to the elements. Try with overflow:auto; and overflow:hidden; You can also try set the scrolling element to position:absolute. But setting heights is my best bet.

Comment: i set a height for the div and used overflow and it works.... then also i set scroll = false for ion content

Comment: but now when i tested it on mobile it is not working , its working well in desktop. In mobile the scroll is not performed

Comment: good it works... for mobile I dunno, try set !important see if it helps.

Comment: @Viveka As you said i set height and give overflow as hidden .. but its not working.. any other way..